# How to shuffle an ArrayList without collections

Tags: java, list, arraylist, shuffle

I have an Array List of "tokens.", each which contains an integer. I need to rearrange them randomly without using built-in collection classes. Any suggestions?

```
TopSpinArray<Integer> list = new TopSpinArray<Integer>(numTokens, spinSize);
    
for(int i = 1; i <= numTokens; i++)
    list.add(i);
```

Comment: The [Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) is pretty easy to implement.

Comment: @Dukeling being pedantic probably, but it's actually called the *Fisher-Yates* algorithm.

Comment: @adrianp Being pedantic, it's ["**also** known as the Knuth shuffle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle). Knuth is easier to remember (for me anyway).

Comment: Why would you shuffle without build in classes? Homework?

Comment: homework instructions say not to use built-in List classes

Answer (score 7):

You can use following code.

> ```
>  public static void shuffleList(List<Integer> a) {
>     int n = a.size();
>     Random random = new Random();
>     random.nextInt();
>     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>       int change = i + random.nextInt(n - i);
>       swap(a, i, change);
>     }
>   }
>
>   private static void swap(List<Integer> a, int i, int change) {
>     int helper = a.get(i);
>     a.set(i, a.get(change));
>     a.set(change, helper);
>   }
> ```

Please note this has been copied from following link

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsShuffle/article.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you can shuffle your class (probably because is not a list: then you can populate a list, shuffle that list and finnally add the suffled data inside your class:

```
    final List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    //fills ArrayList with tokens
    for(int i = 1; i <= numTokens; i++) {
        tempList.add(i);            

    }

    Collections.shuffle(tempList);

    for(Integer i: tempList) {
        al.add(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jabir answer

For swapping any type of object (not just Integer)

```
public static <T> void shuffleList(List<T> a) {
    int n = a.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int change = i + Random.nextInt(n - i);
      swap(a, i, change);
    }
  }

  private static <T> void swap(List<T> a, int i, int change) {
    T helper = a.get(i);
    a.set(i, a.get(change));
    a.set(change, helper);
  }
```